# Building a functional abstraction over remote code execution

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, monads, rpc

I am currently facing the problem of abstracting over remote method invocations (RMI/RPC) within a functional architecture I am working on.

The programming language I'm using is Scala, so I'm not constrained to pure implementations, but I'd like to investigate the possibilities and problems around a functional abstraction of executing code over a network connection.

### What I am looking for

- abstract over remote function calls
- combine remote function calls to form a joint handler for the server side
- `map/comap` both the server-side and the client side proxy objects

I am interested in existing approaches to this problem, maybe in Haskell.

### Possible approach

Since I have not found a good solution so far, I can only show some ideas.

Type class for serialization and deserialization to/from byte streams:

```scala
trait RW[T] {
  def write(t: T, out: OutputStream): Unit
  def read(in: InputStream): T
}
```

The `Handler` trait is used by the server. The handler is given a `context` that provides the server-side information that is required to process the connection (like DB access). Handling a connection can yield a result of type `R`.

```scala
trait Handler[C, R]{
  def handle(c: Context, in: InputStream, out: OutputStream): R
}
```

On the client side, a call looks like an ordinary function.

```scala
trait RemoteCall[A, B]{
  def call(a: A): B
}
```

Now one wants to define remote calls with their logic. This could look like this:

```scala
case class CallDef[A: RW, B: RW, C, R](f: (A, C) => (B, R)) 
  extends Handler[C, R] with RemoteCall[A, B] {
  …
}
```

A `CallDef` defines the logic that must run on the server side by specifying the function `f` that takes both the client data `A` and the server context `C`. It produces an answer for the client `B` and a result for the server `R` that can be used to update the server state.
The types `A` and `B` have to be serializable.

This is about as far as I got. An important missing part is how to compose different `CallDef`s with each other to form joint handlers, and how to add some more functionality to the types, like functor and monad instances. So one can express more complicated computations that consist not only of a single remote invocation.

### Questions

So, do you know of any existing approaches that treat remote invocations in a similar functional way, maybe from Haskell?

Do you know of a simpler functional approach that achieves something comparable?

Comment: Sorry, my answer was obviously wrong so I decided to delete it. And I can't provide a quick answer at the moment. Sorry about that.